# Unable to configure spring security oauth 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to implements oauth 2.0 server using spring security oauth 2.0.

My development environment is following.

Spring framework: 4.2.2 release

Spring oauth2:   2.0.7 release

Apache Tomcat: 8.0.27.0

spring security xml:

**-oauth2.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
           xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
           xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

        <!--bean id="clientDetailServices" class="org.zinzu.mv.oauth2.ZZClientDetailServices"/-->
        <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
            authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
            <anonymous enabled="false" />
            <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
            <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
                parameters -->
            <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
                after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        </http>

        <!-- This is where we tells spring security what URL should be protected 
            and what roles have access to them -->
        <security:http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never" use-expressions="true"
            entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
            <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
            <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
            <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
        </security:http>


        <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="realmName" value="test" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="realmName" value="test/client" />
            <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

        <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                    <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

        <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
        </authentication-manager>


        <!-- This is simple authentication manager, with a hardcoded user/password 
            combination. We can replace this with a user defined service to get few users 
            credentials from DB -->
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service>
                    <user name="beingjavaguys" password="spring@java" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" />
                </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

        <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
            <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
        </bean>


        <!-- This defined token store, we have used inmemory tokenstore for now 
            but this can be changed to a user defined one -->
        <bean id="tokenStore"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

            <bean id="approvalStore"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore">
            <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        </bean>

        <!-- This is where we defined token based configurations, token validity 
            and other things -->
        <bean id="tokenServices"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
            <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
            <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
            <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="120" />
            <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        </bean>
            <bean id="requestFactory"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
            <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
            class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler">
            <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
                    <property name="approvalStore" ref="approvalStore"/>
                    <property name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory"/>
        </bean>

        <oauth:authorization-server
            client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
            user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
            <oauth:authorization-code />
            <oauth:implicit />
            <oauth:refresh-token />
            <oauth:client-credentials />
            <oauth:password />
        </oauth:authorization-server>

        <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
            resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

        <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
            <!-- client -->
            <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
                authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

            <oauth:client client-id="restapp"
                authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
                secret="restapp" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT" />

        </oauth:client-details-service>

        <security:global-method-security
            pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
            <!--you could also wire in the expression handler up at the layer of the 
                http filters. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1452 -->
            <security:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
        </security:global-method-security>

        <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />
        <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />

    </beans>
```

This project raised exception following.

```
24-Oct-2015 14:10:34.415 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
24-Oct-2015 14:10:38.426 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1' while setting constructor argument with key [9]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#1': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_USER')]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 86 more
```

But in spring security project that don't apply spring oauth2, result is successfully.
What's reason?
Thank you for selfless assistance to every body.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this attribute in your `<http>` block

```
    use-expressions="true"

   <http 
        use-expressions="true" 
        pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request 
            parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>
```